# Why is my padding not removed from this image?

Tags: html, css, padding

The left and right padding is not being removed from the image. I want to remove the left and right padding and also removed the background. Help is much appreciated. See the image - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoJX.png)

```
.footertable{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:flex;  
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%; 
}
.footertext{ 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)  
}
.footertext p { 
    color: aliceblue; 
    padding: 0%; 
    margin: 0%;   
}
p {
    margin: 0; 
    color: aliceblue; 
    padding: 0%; 
    
}
ul img{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;   
}
ul a {
    padding: 0%; 
    margin: 0%;
}

<footer>
    <ul class="footertable">
        <li class="footertext"><a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li class="footertext"><p>FaceBook</p></li>
        <li class="footertext"><p>Instagram</p></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
```

Comment: You are not selecting the image in your `ul img` selector. I'd add a class to the image to be more explicit or just select `img` and remove padding

Comment: @ViaTech Unless you've got a conflicting rule (or other rules that are potentially more specific), changing `ul img` to `ul li img` does not help.

Comment: Use a quick reset like: `* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}` And for the image use `img {vertical-align: top;}` since images are inline by default and what you see is most likely the line-height's base.

Comment: @ViaTech The img selector is fine. adding a class made no difference.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan made no difference

Comment: @Zeronir Even with the `vertical-align`? Than use Developer Tools, Highlight the image or some of its parents. Then you'll know what is going on. You don't need us for that task.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i have no idea what developer tools are. Ill have a look now.

Comment: @Zeronir it will your best friend trough your entire frontend-development career so you better get to know it: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/ Right click any of your elements on the website, and hit "Inspect Element" ... welcome to Developer Tools. Than go to "Elements" and lookup the Styles panel. If in trouble go check to Computed Styles tab. There's all you need to resolve your mistery.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Okay thank you for your help. Ill check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<img>` defaults to `display: inline`. You need to use `display: block` on the image element so that you don't get space reserved for descenders of glyphs (which inline elements do):

```
ul img {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;   
}
```

Comment: I tried this. However this did not remove the padding, it just moved the content to the left of the padding.

Comment: @Zeronir what happens if you add `vertical-align: top;` to the image? Please, inspect element, use Developer tools. You'll find out there everything you need. You don't need us to play with the presented rules and the Computed Styles .

Comment: Why on Earth would anyone go set margin and padding to `0` to an image? UL, OL have User Agent default padding, not images.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this removed the small padding at the bottom of the image. Which I assumed was the hyperlink underline.